# Functional Analysis -- Some bounds for the $L^p$ and $C^p$ norms with Sobolev spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Show that there exists some constant $C\in(0,\infty)$ such that the following inequalities hold for all $f\in C^1([a,b])$:
$$\|f\|_{L^p}\leq C\|f\|_{L^r}$$

whenever $1\leq p<r\leq\infty$. And
$$\|f\|_{C^{1-1/p}}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}$$

for any $1\leq p<\infty$.

Proof.

(1) Let $f\in C^1([a,b])$, so that $f$ is integrable with respect to Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on $[a,b]$, and let $1\leq p<r\leq\infty$. By Holder's inequality we have
$$\|f^p\|_{L^1}\leq\|1\|{L^{\frac{r}{r-p}}}\|f^p\|_{L^{\frac{r}{p}}}.$$

That is, we have $$\displaystyle\int_{[a,b]}|f|^p\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\mu([a,b])^{1-\frac{p}{r}}\left(\int_{[a,b]}|f|^{p\cdot\frac{r}{p}}\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\frac{p}{r}}.$$

Taking the $1/p$-th power of both sides yields $$\displaystyle\left(\int_{[a,b]}|f|^p\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq\mu([a,b])^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{r}}\left(\int_{[a,b]}|f|^r\mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{r}},$$ or $$\|f\|_{L^p}\leq\mu([a,b])^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{r}}\|f\|_{L^r}.$$

Taking $C:=\mu([a,b])^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{r}}$ completes the proof of (1).

(2) I cannot figure this out. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** for all $x,y\in [a,b]$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|=\left|\int_x^yf'(t)\,dt\right|$. Now, put absolute values inside, and use Holder's inequality as you did for the previous part. Note that the $1-\frac{1}{p}$ in the Holder norm is exactly equal to $\frac{1}{p'}$, the dual Holder exponent, which arises precisely due to Holder's inequality.

Comment: thank you, this helped